# What is w in orientation doing?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, 2d-pose-estimate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys, I am trying to send a goal to navigation stack, however I just if I set the goal pose as
Location x=5 y=5 z=0
orientation x=0 y=0 z=0 w=0
It wouldn't generate a path.

If I put z as 1 and w as 0, it works sometimes and doesn't work sometime. The weirdest is that sometimes it's spinning to the goal like a fresbee...

My understanding about the goal pose is that z is just the yaw, since we are moving in 2d space there is no pitch and roll. So the question is : is my understanding right? And what is w? What it is doing?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268618/what-is-w-in-orientation-doing-?/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way that ROS defines orientation is with a mathematical concept called a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). They're a good way to represent orientation as they're less ambiguous than roll, pitch, and yaw. But, they have the drawback of being a little difficult to understand. Here's a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Tutorials/Quaternions) that someone wrote to help you understand them.

Now, on to the meat of your question. The reason that you can't generate a path with those components is because if you want to send an orientation equivalent of roll = 0, pitch = 0, and yaw = 0 you need to have the w = 1, not 0. The way that you have the quaternion is not valid.

Many people choose to generate an orientation in roll, pitch, and yaw and convert it to a quaternion. That tutorial will show you how to do this.

Here's another [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/9981/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them/) that should help.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-12**:\

> The way that ROS defines orientation is with something called a quaternion.

This phrasing seemed a little ambiguous to me: it could almost be understood to mean that we 'invented' something new to represent orientation. Quaternions are obviously just a generic mathematical concept.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-12**:
@gvdhoorn I updated the answer with your comment in mind.

**Comment by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on 2017-08-12**:
Thank you so much! But even after I always set the quaternion to 0 0 0 1, the robot is still spinning toward the goal. I If I use the 2D nav goal on rviz, sometimes it still spins. Why is that? How can I avoid that?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-12**:
@rozoalex, no problem, happy to help. You should create a new question that includes (preformatted) terminal output, what you've done, what you expect, and any (preformatted) parameters/configurations that you have for help with your other questions.